# Почему при выводе массива в консоли я вижу не то, что хочу?

Tags: массивы, java

Изучаю время от времени java и столкнулся с вот этим:

```
public static void testArray(){

    int myArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    System.out.println(myArray);
}
```

В консоли я вижу вместо ожидаемого 12345, вот это: [I@42e816

При указании типа String я вижу несколько модифицированную запись: [Ljava.lang.String;@42e816 (но это не то, мне надо, чтобы я мог найти сумму чисел в массиве, а со строками я наверное это не сделаю, или сделаю с большим количеством операций).

В общем, как мне вывести значения массива, и что бы это было в нормальном виде?

Comment: огого! спасибо большое за подсказки. буду изучать пробовать это.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Потому что `Java` не знает, чего вы хотите. Если хотите увидеть массив так, будто это список, то сделайте его списком:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Или просто руками:

```
for (int v : myArray)
    System.out.println(v);
```

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myArray)); --- вижу опять [[I@42e816]

Comment: for (int v : myArray)
    System.out.println(v);
-- эта штука работает)

Comment: забавно, asList() не срабатывает, потому что сигнатура метода - asList(T... a) - в нашем случае T будет не int, а int[] - создастся список массивов. Таким образом, конструкция как раз работает правильно: она выводит 2 скобки, внутри которых содержание списка - один элемент в виде массива.

Answer (score 5):

Метод `toString()` не переопределен в классе массива в Java - а потому он работает там так же, как и в классе Object, т.е. выводит простое имя класса объекта вместе с его [хэшкодом](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29). Для красивого вывода массива можно воспользоваться [соответствующим методом класса Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29).

Comment: Забавно. Проверил (javac 1.6.0_25)

    ArrayTest.java:8: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : method deepToString()


    Arrays.asList(myAr):   [[I@9304b1]
    Arrays.toString(myAr): [1, 2, 3, 4]
    myAr.toString(): [I@9304b1

Comment: @avp а почему `deepToString()` без параметров? Уж не на массиве ли вы его вызвали?

Comment: Да нет. deepToString() я вызывал (пытался) как в книжке

    int [] abc = {1,2,3,4};    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(abc));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(abc));


Сам удивляюсь, почему не компилится. Переставил jdk (на тот же самый) и без результата. Буду пробовать что нибудь еще.

Comment: Поставил jdk1.7.0  С int[] то же самое. А вот Integr [] abc = {1,2,3,4};

Arrays.deepToString(abc) заработало. Проверить для SE 6 не могу, т.к. снес. Может быть проверю завтра на работе.

Comment: добавлю пожалуй что для массива java неявно создает класс (нагляднее всего с generic type):
String []p --> Array<String> p
у класса Array метод toString остался от Object. поэтому такой вывод.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте метод `Arrays.toString()`, преобразующий массив в строку.

Или напишите цикл, выводящий последовательно элементы массива.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `Arrays.toString()` справляется чётко с этой задачей.

В моем случае

```
int[] arrNumbers = {99, 567, 22, 45, 1, 91};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrNumbers));
```

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ примером кода.

Comment: Чем этот ответ отличается от [соседнего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/29763/181472), данного 6 лет назад? )

Comment: Всем привет в этом чатике! 6лет прошло!

Comment: Ответов было много, мне подошло только это решение!