# Создать и заполнить массив NxN

Tags: java, массивы

Создать и заполнить массив NxN, где N  - четное число больше или равно 2, данными согласно следующим правилам. В центре матрицы блок 2х2 заполненный нулями, Далее идут строки столбцы в 1 ячейку значение которых последовательно увеличивается на 1. Помогите решить ,и если не сложно с пояснением пожалуйста! Спасибо.

```
Пример таблицы 4х4
1111
1001
1001
1111

Пример таблицы 6х6
222222
211112
210012
210012
211112
222222

Пример таблицы 8х8
33333333
32222223
32111123
32100123
32100123
32111123
32222223
33333333
```

Задачу получилось решить вот таким образом

```
int[][] array = new int[4][4];

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                array[i][j] =1;
                count++;
                if (count == 6){
                    array[i][j] = 0;
                }
                if (count == 7){
                    array[i][j] = 0;
                }if (count == 10){
                    array[i][j] = 0;
                }
                if (count == 11){
                    array[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Если заполнять так то не понятно как в центр добавить нули 0

```
public static int[][] buildArr(int n) {
        int[][] arr = new int[n][n];
        for (int i = 0, v = n / 2; v-- > 0; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < n - i; j++) {
                arr[i][j] =1;       // верхняя строка
                arr[j][i] =1 ;       // левая колонка
                arr[n-1-i][j] = 1;   // нижняя строка
                arr[j][n-1-i] = 1; // правая колонка
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: У вас примеры неправильные: во втором 5 строк, а в третьем - 7 вместо 6 и 8 соответственно.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Comment: Это учебная задача на циклы и базовую логику.  Постарайтесь решить её самостоятельно, и покажите код ваших попыток.

Comment: 1) `arr[i][j] +=0;` не сбрасывает в 0, а прибавляет 0 к текущему значению ячейки массива -- то есть не меняет в массиве _ничего_  2) Ваш код не решает _общую_ задачу, а пытается заполнить весь массив единицами, а затем для _одного_ индекса вставить 0, так как для четырёх нулей нужны 4 "индекса" - `{6, 7, 10, 11}`.  3) Удалите [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1501589/) этого вопроса.

Comment: Зачем вы заполняете единицами независимо от размера массива, вместо числа `v`, указанного в решении?  Как вы собираетесь заполнять массивы для произвольного четного `N`, указанного в условии?  Чтобы не писались нули в центр, следует исправить условие во внешнем цикле на `v-- > 1`

Comment: Спасибо большое, что помогли разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ решения:

- Смотрим на варианты квадрата в зависимости от его размера и анализируем, какие числа должны быть в него записаны.
  Легко увидеть, что для размера 4х4 числа принадлежат диапазону [0; 1], для 6х6 -- [0; 2], и т.д., то есть для квадрата со стороной `N` максимальное значение можно определить как `N/2 - 1`.
- Заполнение квадрата идет по убыванию значений от периферии к центру.
  Значит, можно заполнить внешние стороны текущим значением (начиная с максимума), затем уменьшить его на 1, перейти на следующую строку/столбец, которые тоже будут сокращены дополнительно на 1.
  Заполнять массив, пока текущее значение больше 0, так как массив будет заполнен нулями при создании условие).
- Можно заполнять сразу 4 стороны квадрата.

Вариант кода:
(*исправил условие `v-- > 1`, чтобы не изменять часть, уже заполненную нулями*)

```java
public static int[][] buildArr(int n) {   
    int[][] arr = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0, v = n / 2; v-- > 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n - i; j++) {
            arr[i][j] =        // верхняя строка
            arr[j][i] =        // левая колонка
            arr[n-1-i][j] =    // нижняя строка
            arr[j][n-1-i] = v; // правая колонка
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

---

Метод для вывода полученного массива -- используется метод `Arrays.toString` для каждой строки, из которой убираются все нецифровые символы при помощи `String::replaceAll("\\D+", "")`:

```java
private static void out(int[][] arr) {
    System.out.println("arr " + arr.length + " x " + arr[0].length);
    for (int[] r : arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r).replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
    }
    System.out.println("----");
}
```

Аналогично, вместо цикла можно было бы использовать Stream API:

```java
private static void out(int[][] arr) {
    System.out.println("arr " + arr.length + " x " + arr[0].length);
    Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(Arrays::toString)
        .map(r -> r.replaceAll("\\D+", ""))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("----");
}
```

Тесты:

```java
out(buildArr(8));
out(buildArr(12));
```

Результаты:

```java
arr 8 x 8
33333333
32222223
32111123
32100123
32100123
32111123
32222223
33333333
----
arr 12 x 12
555555555555
544444444445
543333333345
543222222345
543211112345
543210012345
543210012345
543211112345
543222222345
543333333345
544444444445
555555555555
----
```

Comment: К сожалению это мне не помогло , [[I@28a418fc вот такой вывод получаю

Comment: Вы не можете распечатать содержимое двумерного массива при помощи `System.out.println()`[см. Почему при выводе массива в консоли я вижу не то, что хочу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29759/), так как у массивов своеобразная реализация метода `toString`.  И задача вывода двумерного массива -- _другая_ задача_, которую можно решить при помощи метода `Arrays.deepToString()` или написания отдельного метода для красивого вывода.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста как ты заполняешь массив? я пробовал и 1. и 0 разными вариациями все равно не выходит
            arr[i][j] =        // верхняя строка
            arr[j][i] =        // левая колонка
            arr[n-1-i][j] =    // нижняя строка
            arr[j][n-1-i] = v; // правая колонка

Comment: Не понял вопроса.  [Онлайн демо с кодом, представленным в решении](https://ideone.com/CHzdII).   Что именно не получается?

Comment: Поставил , но к сожалению мои голоса не учитываются пока что

Answer (score -3):

```
   def f(n):
      a = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for __ in range(n)]
      for i in range(n):
         for j in range(n):
           a[i][j] = max(int(abs((n - 1) / 2 - i)), int(abs((n - 1) / 2 - j)))
      return a
```

Comment: В последнее время разница между джавой и питоном стремительно сокращается