# JAVA. Вывести массив

Tags: java

Сразу вставлю код, так как проще будет объяснить что к чему:

```
class Leetcode {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.print(plusOne(new int [] {3, 4, 2, 6, 4}));
    }
    public static int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        for (int i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (digits[i] < 9) {
                digits[i]++;
                return digits;
            }
            digits[i] = 0;
        }

        digits = new int[digits.length + 1];
        digits[0] = 1;
        return digits;
    }
}
```

В общем, мне нужно вывести готовый массив `digits[]` после проделанных операций. Пытался вывести с помощью `System.out.print(plusOne(new int[] {3, 4, 2, 6, 4}));`, но выводится только hash code: `[I@3fee733d`. Пытался даже просто вызвать метод `plusOne(new int[] {3, 4, 2, 6, 4});`, но затея плохая, так как метод сам по себе ничего не выводит, а лишь возвращает массив `digits[]`. (Код не мой, не догадался бы так решить, пока ничего не умею. P.S. код разобрал, понял как работает) Что делать?

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Почему при выводе массива в консоли я вижу не то, что хочу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29759/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто так массив вывести нельзя - выведется его хэшькод в 16ричной системе.

Первый способ - написать руками

```java
public static void printArr(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
}

//вызов
printArr(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
```

Второй способ - воспользоваться готовой функцией из стандартной библиотеке

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
//...
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}));
```

Comment: Понял, как работает `toString()`, создал массив, вывел его с помощью данного метода. Даже создал метод, который выводит массив, все работает. Но, почему-то не получается вывести измененный в ходе вычислений массив `digits`, который возвращает метод `plusOne`. Код скину в ответе на свой вопрос. P.S. не там где надо добавил строку вывода. Сейчас додумался наконец-таки и все работает. Спасибо :)

Comment: У вас правильно решенная задачка, отправьте ее на сабмит и двигайтесь дальше)

Comment: Она правильная потому что решение не мое. Так как не знал, каким образом решить данную задачу в силу своей неопытности, решил разобрать выполнение этой задачи другим человеком. Но так как мне интересно, захотел вывести измененный массив, а не просто вернуть его.